# download font from font-face/website

Tags: fonts, download

I want  to download a font from site.The font is used in  @font-face rule. I have downloaded it but not working, rather showing Invalid font.

Is there are any way to download font from a site??

Comment: i have the same question, are there any way to get (download) and use a special font that used in a webpage ? like lenovo_bold font in the menu of this page
http://www.thedostore.com/smartphones.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends...If the website that has that font uses a CMS or cloak to hide the link/directory of the font, no, not quite, but if the directory is typed inside the css document of a website, then you can always view the source of the website, access the main .css file and look for something like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Your italic typeface";
  src: url("type/filename-ital.eot");
  src: local("&#x263A;"),
    url("type/filename-ital.woff") format("woff"),
    url("type/filename-ital.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("type/filename-ital.svg#filename-ital") format("svg");
}
```

The above is actually an example of a hidden font link, if it wasn't hidden you could access the font by typing www.thewebsite.com/type/fi;ema,e-ital.otf  :)

Hope this helps